# Parameterized reusable blocks with Jinja2 (Flask) templating engine

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In Jinja2 templating engine (using Flask), I want to achieve something like that:

```
{% reusable_block avatar(user) %}
     <img src='{{ user.avatar }}' title='{{ user.name }}'/> 
{% reusable_block %}
```

and then in various places:

```
{% for u in users %}
    {% call avatar(u) %}
{% endfor %}
```

However I can't find such a feature (I made up `reusable_blocks` for this question) in Jinja documentation.  What I need is basically reusable blocks that can take parameters. Any ideas know how can I do that with Jinja2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use macros.

```
{% macro input(name, value='', type='text', size=20) -%}
    <input type="{{ type }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{value|e }}" size="{{ size }}">
{%- endmacro %}


<p>{{ input('username') }}</p>
<p>{{ input('password', type='password') }}</p>
```

More documentation [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros)