# Can you create components in Flask/Jinja to insert in various templates

Tags: python, jinja2

Let's say I make a really cool search box layout that I'd like to reuse

eg.

```
<div class='someClass'>
    <input class='fancyInput'>
</div>
```

Is it possible to reuse that snippet in other templates in the same way I can extend upon a template, but instead "import" a snippet so to speak. Like the reserve of `{% extend %}

I'd like to have html blocks that I can reuse but insert into different areas depending on the page.

Currently every time I want to use that block of HTML I have to hard code it in.

here's a pseudo html/jinja example

The snippet

```
{% component fancyInput %} # not real jinja

<div class='someClass'>
    <input class='fancyInput'>
</div>

{% endcomponent %}
```

Then lets say on a random page somewhere

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='container'><p>Some text!</p></div>
    {% import component fancyInput}
</body>
</html>
```

The rendered HTML would be

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <p>Some text!</p>
    </div>
    <div class='someClass'>
        <input class='fancyInput'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Jinja2` uses macros. Once a Macro is defined, it can be called on to render elements.

So if you define a macro in a template like:

```
  {% macro newComponent(text) -%}
      <div class='container'><p>{{text}}</p></div>
  {%- endmacro %}
```

Then it can be called on in any file with

```
{{ newComponent('Insert Text') }}
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#macros)

Also Stack Overflow post on macros
[Parameterized reusable blocks with Jinja2 (Flask) templating engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106741/parameterized-reusable-blocks-with-jinja2-flask-templating-engine)

Comment: If I want to include JavaScript with this macro that could also be reused elsewhere, how would I achieve that?

Comment: After implementing your answer i also found the possibility of making a new helper .html with macros and importing it in the main .html pages. Having a html with different components of the app it very usefull and clean (especially when using tailwinds). See import here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#import

Answer (score 7):

Use `include` to include whole template file in your current template, [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#include)

Example from documentation:

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
    Body
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Macros are the standard way to do this (as answered before), but as our project grew bigger, it started to be bit messy.
I was trying different approaches to this, and finally I went with following:

Inspired by github [ViewComponent](https://viewcomponent.org) library (for Rails), I started working with different "architecture" for reusable HTML code (can be named TemplateComponents as template in Flask == view elsewhere):

Components are classes, in my case located in `app/components/`.
Component itself does some logic and then renders jinja template (with minimum logic from `app/templates/components/`
They are used by helper functions (defined in same place), these helpers are registered by flask to be globally accessible, eg.(`application.add_template_global(icon)`)

What are the benefits for me?

- components as classes are easily testable
- I can harness power of OOP.
- logic in Python is (to me) more readable than in jinja2

Here's example how it can be set up:

```py
# app/__init__.py


def create_app():
    (...)
    from app.components import register_all_components

    register_all_components(application)
    (...)
```

```py
# app/components/__init__.py

from .links import link_to, link_to_edit


def register_all_components(application):
    application.add_template_global(link_to)
    application.add_template_global(link_to_edit)
```

```py
# app/components/links.py
from app.components import Component


# core
class Link(Component):
    def __init__(self, path, value, **kwargs):
        super(Link, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.path = path
        self.value = value


# helpers
def link_to(obj, **kwargs):
    path = obj.path_to_show()
    value = kwargs.pop("value", obj.default_value_link)

    return Link(path=path, value=value, **kwargs).render()


def link_to_edit(obj, **kwargs):
    from app.components import icon
    path = obj.path_to_edit()
    value = kwargs.pop("value", icon("edit"))

    return Link(path=path, value=value, **kwargs).render()
```

```py
# app/components/base.py

from flask import render_template as render
from flask import Markup


class Component:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.kwargs["data"] = self.kwargs.pop("data", {})

    def render(self):
        return Markup(render(self.template, **self.attributes))

    @property
    def template(self):
        folder = getattr(self, "folder", f"{self.__class__.__name__.lower()}s")
        file = getattr(self, "file", f"{self.__class__.__name__.lower()}")

        return f"components/{folder}/{file}.html.j2"

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        # All public variables of the view are passed to template
        class_attributes = self.__class__.__dict__
        view_attributes = self.__dict__
        all_attributes = class_attributes | view_attributes
        public_attributes = {
            k: all_attributes[k] for k in all_attributes if not k.startswith("_")
        }

        # kwargs has higher priority, therefore rewrites public attributes
        merged_values = {**public_attributes, **self.kwargs}
        return merged_values
```

```
# app/templates/components/links/link.html.j2

<a
    href="{{ path }}"
    {% if class %} class="{{ class }}" {% endif %}
>{{ value }}</a>
```

This is super-early stage of how I manage this, just wanted to share it as I was for a long time thinking and changing how we manage this sustainably in our project.

Hope it gives some inspiration!

Comment: You may find https://jinjax.scaletti.dev/ useful. I just stumbled upon it today.

Comment: Cool, thanks @HonzaJavorek!
I don't like usage of custom HTML tags much, but its a nice inspiration nevertheless.
I started my own flask extension (based on my answer here) in this [repo](https://github.com/janpeterka/flask-template-components)